# Android ESC/POS protocol printing in Cyrillic

Tags: escpos

I bought a no-name Android ESC/POS printer, it support Bluetooth. I need help in printing Cyrillic symbols in Windows-1251 charset. What I do first:

`\x1B\x40` (ESC @ to initialize printer)

`\xD5\xD3\xC9\n` (the text that I need to print, standard Windows-1251 symbols, but it shows me some abracadabra :))

I should say, that the charset is set to Windows-1251 on the printer (by the exe tool that comes with it)

Also I tried command `\x1B\x74\x49` (it sets the Windows-1251 manually, but there is no effect). Any ideas what we can do with it? Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

You can try my app that print cyrillic text:  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pe.diegoveloper.printerserverapp

Configure your ESC/POS printers on 'Quick Printer' and print from your app.

Answer (score 2):

I tried many variants and after [this manual](http://sparkag.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/ESC_POS-AK912-English-Command-Specifications-V1.4.pdf) end up with this character code page settings { 27, 116, 9 }

`outputStream.write(new byte [] { 27, 116, 9 });
outputStream.write("Привет Мир".getBytes("cp866"));
outputStream.write(PrinterCommands.LF);`

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert your text to cp866.

And set code page in printer via ESC/POS command into 17.

Answer (score 0):

With [Universal Cyriclic decoder](https://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en) you can find your source encoding/decoding.

Enter in decoded field your output text. For example 袩褉懈胁械褌.
Select source encoding UTF-8.
Then find your wanted decoding charset by selecting field "display as".